# How can I create multiple relationships to the same table in EF7(Core)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to construct a migration, but it's stumbling over the following class:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Nullable<int> PreviousUnitID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PreviousUnitID")]
    public Unit PreviousUnit { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> SubsequentUnitID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubsequentUnitID")]
    public Unit SubsequentUnit { get; set; }
}
```

"The navigation property '' cannot be added to the entity type 'Unit' because a navigation property with the same name already exists on entity type 'Unit'.

I'm assuming this slightly peculiar navigation is to blame so I've left out the rest of the class. Does anyone know of a way I can circumvent this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with RC1.

Issue:

- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4069
- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4261

Development Chain:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/4239

> rowanmiller commented 8th January
>
> That would be #4069 which is fixed in our nightly builds and will ship in RC2.

Answer (score 0):

use virtual instead of unit

```
public class Unit
{
public int UnitID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PreviousUnitID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> SubsequentUnitID { get; set; }

public Virtual PreviousUnit { get; set; }
public Virtual SubsequentUnit { get; set; }
}
```

create as many relationship as you want

Comment: I either don't have the library which Virtual class is from, or you meant to make PreviousUnit / SubsequentUnit a virtual property, at which point I'm still using the Unit class and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Negative - I rolled back to migration 0 and tried again, still hitting the same issue, so it has not yet been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use the virtual keyword:

```
public virtual Unit PreviousUnit { get; set; }
public virtual Unit SubsequentUnit { get; set; }
```

Complete code:

```
public class Unit
{
public int UnitID { get; set; }
...
public Nullable<int> PreviousUnitID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("PreviousUnitID")]
public virtual Unit PreviousUnit { get; set; }

public Nullable<int> SubsequentUnitID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("SubsequentUnitID")]
public virtual Unit SubsequentUnit { get; set; }
}
```

This also enables lazy loading of the Units.

edit:
Maybe this could also help: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3911

Comment: I don't believe lazy loading is configured in EF7/EFCore. But unfortunately, regardless, I still get the same navigation property issue when creating the Migration.

Comment: I thought it could help but I don't tested it with migration because I don't know exactly your last configuration. Maybe this could help:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3911

Comment: Oh thank you! I'll keep an eye on that, perhaps it wasn't the code then, just the earlier migration.

Comment: Hmm, it appears this is a bug that is being patched in RC2. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4069